# Chinese Remainder Theorem (uniqueness proof)

Tags: proof-explanation, chinese-remainder-theorem

I would like to get an explanation of how to proof the uniqueness of the solution of s system of congruences. I have already read 4 books about it but none of them does not explain me an specific part of the reasoning. The following image has also this part

[image]

I don't understand why $lcm(m_1,\dots,m_r)\mid (X_1-X_2)$.

I tried to prove it in a simpler case, considering that $m_1$ and $m_2$ (relatively prime) are divisors $a$. Then

$$a=m_1x=m_2y$$

For some integers $x$ and $y$. But I couldn't combine this and the fact of $m_1r+m_2s=1$, with $r, s\in \mathbb{Z}$, to conclude that $m_1m_2\mid a$.

Comment: $X_1-X_2$ is a common multiple. Any common multiple is divisible by the least common multiple.

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma:** If $m_1,m_2,\dots,m_k$ are non-zero integers, then let $M=[m_1,\dots,m_k],$ the LCM. If $N$ is an integer such that $m_i\mid N$ for all $i=1,\dots,k,$ then $M\mid N.$

**Proof:** By division algorithm, there are integers $q,r$ with  $N=Mq+r,$ and $0\leq r <M.$

But then $r=N-Mq$ is divisible by each $m_i.$ So, $r=0,$ or else we’ve found a smaller positive common multiple, contradicting that $M$ is the least common multiple

Comment: So as $m_i\mid N$ by hypothesis and $Mq/m_i=m_1\cdots m_{i-1}m_{i+1}\cdots m_k$, then $r$ is divisible by $m_i$, right? That's why $r$ needs to be zero, to avoid the contradiction

Comment: No $Mq/m_i$ is not the right hand. First, in general, $M$ is not $m_1m_2\cdots m_k,$ and second there needs to be a $q$ on the right-hand side. Literally, because each $m_i$ is a factor of $M$ and $N,$ each $m_i$ is a factor of $r=N-qM.$ @MarcosPaulo